Laravel Blade PHP Expression returns undefined variable
I have something like this in my controller passed to blade
$fields = [
            'productCode' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'validation' => 'required|min:4|max:10',
                'label' => 'Product Code',
            ],
    'productLine' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => ['Motorcycles' => 'Motorcycles', 'Classic Cars' => 'Classic Cars', 'Trucks and Buses' => 'Trucks and Buses'],
                'validation' => 'required',
                'label' => 'Product Line',
            ],

in my view blade
<?php 
        foreach ($fields as $field => $param): 
            $options = [];
            if (!empty($param['options'])):
                $options = $param['options'];
            endif;
        ?>
            <x-larastrap::{{ $param['type'] }} 
                name="{{ $field }}" 
                label="{{ $param['label'] }}"
                <?php if (!empty($options)): ?>
                :options="$options"
                <?php endif; ?>
            />
        <?php endforeach ?>

I am getting undefined variable $options but the $options value is being set (i can print_r and see the values. I suspect this has to do with how blade handles php expression. i can't seems to be able to figure out why

Your blade template does not follow the "Laravel" style of handling UI, modify your blade to this:
@foreach ($fields as $field => $param)
    <x-larastrap::{{ $param['type'] }}
        name="{{ $field }}"
        label="{{ $param['label'] }}"
        @if (!empty($param['options'])
            :options="@json($param['options'])" <!-- or {!! json_encode($param['options']) !!} -->
        @endif
    />
@endforeach

I've used json_encode() to properly encode the $options array for passing it to the component as a prop. This should ensure that the $options variable is properly defined and passed to the component without any issues.

parse error - syntax error, unexpected token "{",  :options="{&quot;Motorcycles&quot; is the output. I've tried with ```:options="json_encode($options)", same problem. Undefined variable $options

try modifying :options="{{ json_encode($options) }}" to :options='@json($options)'

@cicakman you can either use @json($array) or {!! json_encode($array) !!}

Maybe you can try something like this
@foreach ($fields as $field => $param)
<x-larastrap::{{ $param['type'] }}
    name="{{ $field }}"
    label="{{ $param['label'] }}"
    @if (!empty($param['options']))
        :options="{{ json_encode($param['options']) }}"
    @endif
/> 
@endforeach


the $options variable is encoded as a JSON string using json_encode. Then, within the Blade template, you can pass this JSON string as the options attribute, which will be decoded and used as needed.
@php
$options = json_encode($options); // Convert options to JSON string to pass to Blade template
@endphp


Probably the best way to dynamically add components in your template is the "Dynamic Components" feature native of Laravel:
@foreach ($fields as $field => $param)
    <x-dynamic-component
        :component="sprintf('larastrap::%s', $param['type'])"
        :params="[
            'name' => $field, 
            'label' => $param['label'], 
            'options' => $param['options'] ?? null
        ]"
    />
@endforeach

This approach is also mentioned in the Larastrap documentation.
